# Правильная передача параметров в функцию

Tags: php, ооп

Приведу пример. Есть функция `foo`, в которую необходимо передать два свойства двух разных объектов. Здесь возникает вопрос, как правильнее передать эти свойства - напрямую, или передать объекты, а потом в теле функции извлечь из них свойства?

```
function foo($id1, $id2){
    return $id1+$id2
}
```

или

```
function foo(Obj $obj1, Obj $obj2){
    return $obj1->id+$obj2->id;
}
```

Понятно, что с точки зрения практичности лучше первый вариант. Но какой вариант учтет правильные подходы ООП-программирования и принципы SOLID? Не будет ли первый вариант им противоречить?

Comment: Очень зависит от того, что делает функция и того, что из себя представляют объекты. Ваш вопрос слишком общий и чёткого ответа на него дать не получится. Пожалуйста, добавьте в свой вопрос детали по вашей конкретной ситуации, чтобы мы смогли вам помочь.

Comment: Добавлю конкретики: функция добавляет запись в таблицу. Эта запись будет отображать "дружбу" двух пользователей, то есть оба параметра- это id двух записей из таблицы users. Так вот - как лучше: в качестве параметров этой функции передать сразу id или объекты user? Сразу задал вопрос более общим, так как думаю, что  вопрос актуален для многих ситуаций.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что вашу задачу с дружбой вообще нужно сделать по-другому, нежели мудрить))

Comment: Работаю с фреймворком. так что здесь ничего не "мудрю". И, к слову, выдержка с официального хелпа:                                        public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $flight = new Flight;
       $flight->name = $request->name;
       $flight->save();
    }

Comment: в вашем случае исключительно первый вариант. Зачем передавать объект ради одного поля? Другое дело, если функция будет меняться. И как сказали выше, наверняка есть более легки пути реализации данной задачи.

Comment: А ещё, подумайте, является ли ваша функция частью бизнес-слоя (Business Logic Layer), или же частью слоя доступа к данным (Data Access Layer)? Кто будет эту функцию использовать и как? Как она может изменить своё поведение в будущем? Важно ли ей в будущем сохранять сигнатуру, чтобы предотвратить breaking changes? Если на все эти вопросы вы ответите "не знаю" или "это неважно", то и неважно, какой из вариантов реализации функции вы выберете.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендации от сторонников чистого кода вполне ясны - правильнее передавать минимальные зависимости, то есть данные, а не объекты, в которых эти данные содержатся. Чем меньше функция требует знаний о внешнем мире, тем легче ее тестировать и сопровождать. Такова теория.

На практике же часто есть сомнения вида "а вдруг мне понадобится что-то еще и придется менять сигнатуру" или "стоит ли прокинуть текстовый ip или IpAddress, что есть ValueObject для ip".

Так что лучше начинать с минимального контракта, но учитывать текущие и будущие требования функции, то есть насколько сложно будет менять сигнатуру для добавления полей или замены на объект и особенности данных самого объекта.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо выбирать по архитектуре этого участка когда.

Вариант 1: foo($id1, $id2)
Если функция foo это действительно функция и представляет собой компонент логики приложения в виде одной функции, то лучше передавать конкретные значения. Чем меньше локальных зависимостей, тем лучше.

Вариант 2: foo(Obj $obj1, Obj $obj2)
Если функция foo это метод класса компонента логики приложения, то лучше передавать экземпляр класса (объект) и в аргументах функции запрашивать конкретный класс для проверки типа. Это обеспечивает безопасность когда и повышает удобство разработки.

Answer (score -2):

Главный принцип - это принцип целесообразности.
Зачем передавать целые объекты, когда нужны только их отдельные свойства?
Тем более, семантика: допустим, Ваша функция (а точнее метод) складывает два числа и Вы назовете её `summarize`. Всем вокруг ясно, что она суммирует, по не всем понятно, почему объекты.

Другое дело, если планируется в будущем использовать *и другие* свойства этих объектов. Тогда подход с объектами верный.

Comment: Минусанул, т.к. ответ не рассматривает все возможные варианты, а лишь частный случай. Причем этот частный случай на практике встречается не так уж часто.

Comment: Я бы тоже хотел увидеть ответ, который охватит все возможные варианты. Если Вы его уже пишете, желаю Вам запастись кофе и крепкой клавиатурой.

Comment: Мне тут некий @Ипатьев запретил отвечать на вопросы, если я не уверен в ответе. Я сам сомневаюсь в точности своих знаний в этом глубоком теоретическом вопросе. Подождем Ипатьева. (если что, я абсолютно серьезно, а то перечитал, понял, что можно в этом сомневаться.)